# Linear search in Python using Dictionary

Tags: python

I have created a dictionary and given some arbitrary keys and values. I want the user to input the name he wants to search for in my dictionary and I have created a loop to search for that name using linear search to print found or not found using the below code:

```
person = dict()
person["Ravi"] = "789"
person["Ram"] = "850"
person["Raju"] = "995"
print(person)
name = input()
y = None
for key in person.keys():
    if key == name:
        print("found")
    else:
        y = False
if not y:
    print("Not found")
```

but my program is printing Not found every time even though I enter some name which is existing in keys like Ravi exactly in same case. can anyone please find any bug in this code causing this error?

Comment: Both `None` and `False` are falsey, so your `if` condition is always true.

Comment: Why are you doing linear search of dictionary keys? Just use `if name in person:`

Comment: You're setting `y = False` even if some other iteration found a match.

Comment: then how should i print not found any other way?

Comment: Set `y = False` before the loop. When you find a match, set `y = True`. You don't need to do anything for a non-match.

Comment: You can also break out of the loop when you find the match.

Comment: Also see the linked question, it shows how to use the `else` block of a Python loop to do something when you don't break out. Then you don't need the variable.